# youtube videos downloading issue through idm

Tags: firefox, video, youtube, idm

The download link of idm is not showing whenever i am playing any video on youtube. i tried to configure the idm setting by checking the browser options i.e. open idm>downloads>options>general, than capture downloads from the following browsers. a pop up window is showing (**IDM cannot find mozila firefox on your computer. Please locate the browser executable file on the next dialog box**).In that dialog box i am unable to add the exe file of IDM. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: IDM is Windows software. Are you running it in Ubuntu?

Comment: yes using wine.

Comment: Then the software won't find Firefox obviously. It may find Firefox for Windows if installed (with wine) but that's far from guaranteed. The emulated environment isn't the same as the full OS it tries to emulate. It really makes no sense using foreign software when you have plenty of native ones. If you are so dependent on Windows software, use Windows OS.

Comment: Hey if you want idm like software use xdm...u need jdk-jre in ubuntu and executable file of xdm.. download xdm.tar.gz.or install usig ppa... Google it :).. lot more better than IDM

Answer (score 1):

> (IDM cannot find mozila firefox on your computer. Please locate the browser executable file on the next dialog box

IDM is windows software. In your case you have it running in WINE.

> How to resolve the issue?

Install firefox in WINE and if it does not find it itself you can then point to the windows executable for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It's my pleasure to be here & answer your question & I hope it would help you out.
If IDM is not able to download videos directly from Video players such as Facebook & Youtube etc then the issue might be with the IDM chrome extension.

I had the same issue, too. But recently, I found a link that helped me integrating the extension into my browser.
If you are using Chrome Browser then you must download the IDM Chrome extension from Here: **[Download Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idm-integration-module/ngpampappnmepgilojfohadhhmbhlaek)**

If the above link isn't helping you or you are using any other browser then you must download extracted IDM extension which I found here> [Download IDM Extension](http://www.softquack.com/extensions-addons/idmgcext-idm-chrome-extension-download/).